# How to animate a camera to follow an object

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine, camera

I am creating an animation that is mainly focused on an moving and rotating object, the objects animation speeds up and slows down based on the music I plan on adding. I have the object animated the way I like but I need the camera to follow the object. I tried parenting them together and setting a track to but the problem then is that camera also follows the rotation of that object.

Is there anyway to like set just the camera's x location to be the same as the object's x location animation so that the camera follows the rotating object without actually rotating it's self?

Answer (score 2):

Create an Empty and parent the camera to that instead of the actual object. Then add a [Copy Location constraint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/constraints/transform/copy_location.html) to the Empty to copy the location of the object, ignoring the rotation. To get a delay between the object and the camera (so the camera lags behind the motion) you can use the Slow Parent option when parenting the camera to the Empty.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_9tSMBNop4&feature=youtu.be.

Comment: Here is the animation I made. If you have any feedback for how to better animate or any tips I would love to hear them. This was my first time actually using the graph editor so I am trying to get better in using it and making better animations so I can better understand animating in blender before moving to animating and rigging charachters.